# open Fragment from ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have an ActionBarDrawerToggle which contains many fragments for example

RootFragment
LoginFragment
RegistrationFragment

from RootFragment i navigate to another activity like

```
Intent activity = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),TestActivity.class);
activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(activity);
getActivity().finish();
```

how to navigate from TestActivity to LoginFragment

i'm using the following code for example:

```
startActivity(new Intent(TestActivity.this, RegistrationFragment.class));
                                            finish();
```

and the app crashes with the following message RegistrationFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Any help?

Comment: your `RegistrationFragment` should be inside an `Activity` right?

Comment: MainActivity contains ActionBarDrawerToggle so to answer your question is MainActivity sorry i'm very new to android world

Comment: looks like you don't know what `Fragment` is and how its used. Read this before using `Fragment`: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: well my question is how to open from MainActivity a fragment

Answer (score 1):

the `startActivity` method is for starting an `Activity` not for adding `Fragment`. for adding `Fragment` you should do this :

```
      FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
      ft.replace(R.id.container, new RegistrationFragment());
      ft.commit();
```

and R.id.container is your fragment container's id in your xml

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass Fragment class as an argument in startActivity method. You have to pass Activity class there and when it'll be created show appropriate Fragment in just started Activity. In your case do:

```
startActivity(new Intent(TestActivity.this, ActionBarActivity.class));
finish();
```

And then in `onCreate` method of ActionBarActivity add fragment.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(containerViewId , RegistrationFragment).commit();
```